# Accordance of the adjectives with the polite form "вы"

Tags: formality, согласование

How do we have to accord the adjectives with the polite form "вы"? Plural or singular? 
Should we, for example, tell a man "вы красивый", or "вы красивые"? (logically I would use singular, but I want to be sure!!).

Answer (score 10, accepted):

The predicate (short) form is mandatorily plural: `вы красивы`. However, when full-form adjectives are used colloquially as predicates, singular sounds more natural: `вы такая красивая`, etc.

Answer (score 0):

Changing pronoun "ты" to polite form "вы" doesn't affect adjective.

Example: 
"Вы красивый мужчина" - singular form, masculine gender.
“Вы красивая женщина” - singular form, feminine gender.

Comment: Those are not very relevant examples because the adjective in both agrees with a noun. The question is what do you do when you only have the pronoun to go upon.

Comment: tell a man "вы красивый": Subject in the sentence in singular form, masculine gender person, replaced with pronoun.

Comment: That's different. However, that's only in case you use the full form of the adjective as a predicate, which only happens in colloquial speech. The short form must be plural: `вы красивы`.

Comment: Your point is correct but it’s not applicable for this particular case. "вы красивый" is not a whole sentence.

Comment: @Soumiruzu It is a complete sentence. Only, with full form adjective a noun is always implied, so they always agree with a real person without cheating, even when there is polite "вы".

Comment: "Вы красивый." - complete sentence.
"вы красивый" - accordance example.

Answer (score -1):

In colloquial speech both variants can be used. However, I would prefer to use the first one, especially in formal written language