# Вы used with plural verbs and adjectives

Tags: грамматика

It is apparent that вы is used with the plural ending in past tense verbs regardless of whether or not it is plural in context.

Does the same hold true for short adjectives (but not long ones)?

Comment: Yes, exactly. I believe there's nothing to add. Should this question be closed?

Comment: Usage of "Вы" in accordance with adjectives is also discussed here: http://russian.stackexchange.com/questions/8227/accordance-of-the-adjectives-with-the-polite-form-%D0%B2%D1%8B

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Yes, it does:

> Вы проницательны.